# windows task manager-limit hours of weekly task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, taskscheduler

I want to schedule a task through task manager, It should be weekly task but should work on different days, keeping hours in mind.
Suppose it should work on monday from 10 pm to 6 am.
Is it also possible that it doesnt kill/close the process forcefully, for ex. some task is running it can exceed till 7 am in morning until the execution is completed, then it can close down.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to create your task with C# application and call that exe in `Task Scheduler` windows app [as it has wide variety of scheduling features] instead of writing you own scheduling library IMHO.

Comment: Hi, In my application i need task scheduler to run the exe, do you want to say that the exe(which is c# exe) will run task scdeuler again using API's, In this case task scdeuler will run twice?

Comment: No need to use any API. Consider you need to schedule job to take backup of DB from ur C# application. You need to write a C# app to take backup. Then open `Task Scheduler` windows app and create a new schedule to call this application.I will request you to update urself on using Task Scheduler windows App